# LiftMaster garage opener not working in 2017 Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, camry, accessories

I have a new Toyota Camry 2017 which features a HomeLink garage door opener. I have a garage from LiftMaster (I don't know any details because I did not buy and/or install it). The remote looks like:

[image: Remote Control]

I followed the procedure in the manual exactly and everything happens as stated in the manual:

*The HomeLink(R) compatible receiver in your vehicle has 3 buttons which can be programmed to operate 3 different devices. Refer to the programming method below appropriate for the device. Programming the HomeLink(R):*

1. *Point the remote control transmitter for the device 1 to 3 in. from the HomeLink(R) control buttons*. **Done**.
2. *Press and hold one of the HomeLink(R) buttons and the transmitter button*. **Done**. *When the HomeLink(R) indicator light changes from a slow to a rapid flash, you can release both buttons*. **This happens after a couple of seconds and I release the buttons**
3. *Test the HomeLink(R) operation by pressing the newly programmed button. If a HomeLink(R) button has been programmed for a garage door, check to see if the garage door opens or closes.*. **It does not**.

I found Youtube videos which connect the same LiftMaster remote which their car so I am sure it's HomeLink compatible (also the fact that it programs successfully).

What could be the problem?

For reference, this is the garage door:

[image: Garage Door]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I feel your plight, if you've followed the directions accurately, and you've received expected feedback from the devices, I'm not sure how we are going to be able to help you with this?

Comment: Well, something has to be wrong, otherwise it would work and I was hoping somebody uses this (either with similar or even the same devices) and can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you post the procedure (edit your question) and put in *exactly* what you've already done? Step-by-step?

Comment: I updated the question. While doing this, I found that the issue could be a *rolling code system* in which I think I also have to train the garage for the car. I will try to check this more closely and update the question (or answer) appropriately.

Comment: On my garage door opener, I had to program the garage door opener to receive the signal from the HomeLink in order for it to work. It seems sort of foreign to me you'd program the HomeLink to match the existing device. I hope someone has some better information on this stuff than I do.

Comment: IIRC, I had a similar issue.  You have to program the homelink, and then prep the opener with a small button to accept a "new" remote.  This syncs everyone to the rolling code.  Ultimately I think the idea is that somebody can't program their own remote with access to *only* your original transmitter - they also must have access to the actual opener electronics housed in the motor assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a newer liftmaster and it has a learning button on the opener itself. Look for a learn button, usually purple on your opener and push it, when the light comes on you push the button in the car and it is programed.

Answer (score 1):

It is amazing what can be found on the Internet. According to the [Liftmaster site](https://www.liftmaster.com/liftmaster-security-2-0-garage-door-openers-homeli) there could be a number of reasons this isn't working. There are various scenarios related to the age of the opener vs the age of the car, and whether the HomeLink system is aftermarket or OEM.

Regardless, they offer a link to [HomeLink](http://www.homelink.com/program/garagedooropener) which has a handy look up for your car and model of door opener. This gives you specific instructions for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the HomeLink system in my car, and ended up purchasing a 'HomeLink Repeater' kit, which receives the signal from the car and forwards it to the garage opener. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GWD4LUI) is a link to the one I purchased via Amazon.

I believe the issue stemmed from a change in security measures, basically meaning the HomeLink system and your garage door opener speak 2 different languages, for which the repeater acts as an interpreter.